# Limiting sudo access for certain tasks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo, access-control

I am trying to implement an functionality where I need to limit the acccess of user that currently has sudo permissions to certain processes or files. I need the user to be able to certain tasks like start MongoDB processes or restart Docker services, but on the same time not be able to interact with any system processes or antivirus processes running on the system.

is there a way I can limit the sudo access in a customised way?

Comment: see [man sudoers](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

To add user specifications to the sudoers file:

```
visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

To create a whitelist of commands users are allowed to run: `CmndAlias ALL <list of commands>`

To use Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM): `su -c <command>`

These commands will help to restrict what commands a user can run with sudo privileges, provide root access to users in the wheel group, and create a whitelist of commands users are allowed to run.

Comment: Naming the list of commands `ALL` is probably misleading. Perhaps an alias of `LIMITED_USE` would be more informative. If you add the user to the `wheel` group, you are giving the user full privileges even with the alias defined. You probably want a line like `username ALL=ALL LIMITED_USE`. Finally, `sudo` and `su` are very different functionally and have no overlap in the configuration.

Comment: Using an alias such as "LIMITED_USE" would be more informative and clear, that's for sure.you can add the following line to the sudoers file:


`Cmnd_Alias LIMITED_USE = /usr/bin/mongod, /usr/bin/docker`
This creates an alias called "LIMITED_USE" that includes the MongoDB and Docker commands. Then you can give access to the user to this alias by updating the sudoers file by adding a line like this:

`john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: LIMITED_USE`

Comment: @Mixtutor your comment should be an [edit] of your answer.